# Can't find a pattern in a String

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I Have this String which contains "Tulos: +1" many times and I try to find how many times "Tulos: +1" occurs in that String, but it does not work.

It does not return an error. It just does not find it. That Toast is just for testing. And it always says that count2 = 0. By the way, that query works fine.

I think the problem is caused by the plus character, but I cannot figure it out.

```
count2 = 0;

while(query1.moveToNext()){

    String str2 = query1.getString(0);

    Toast.makeText(kortti.this,
            str2 + count2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("Tulos: +1");
    Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(str2);
    while (m2.find()){
        count2 +=1;
        System.out.println(count2);
    }

}
```

Comment: It was that plus sing... I just did not know what to do. So the right way is to write "Tulos: "+"\\+"+"1". I just had to add \\+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string `"Tulos: +1"` says `Tulos:`, followed by **one or more space `" "` characters**, then `1`.

If you want an actual plus, then you should escape it.

`"Tulos: \\+1"`

Comment: Yeah I figured that out (In the comment) but still thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just try: String.indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)  has high performance

```
int count = 0;
int start = 0;
while(true) {
    int index = str2.indexOf("Tulos: +1", start);
    if (index < 0) break;

    start += 9; // 9 is length of "Tulos: +1"
    count++;
}
return count;
```

Comment: You could use `"Tulos: +1".length()`, by the way